# Filter file types with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

I am using JFileChooser to select a file and I am trying to limit the display to show only jpg or jpeg files.  I have tried FileFilter and ChoosableFileFilter and it is not limiting the file selection.  Here is my code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", new String[] {"jpg", "jpeg"});
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  debug.put("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
  File selectedFile = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
...
```

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. I see all the directories. Then the files are filtered by extension.

Comment: Same for me. It works perfectly , JDK 7 and W7

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

   public String getDescription() {
       return "JPG Images (*.jpg)";
   }

   public boolean accept(File f) {
       if (f.isDirectory()) {
           return true;
       } else {
           String filename = f.getName().toLowerCase();
           return filename.endsWith(".jpg") || filename.endsWith(".jpeg") ;
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean "it's not limiting the selection" as in "it's allowing the option for any file type"? If so, then try `JFileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(boolean)`.

```
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
```

According to the [JFileChooser documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(boolean)), it should tell it not to add the all-file-types file filter to the file filter list.

Answer (score 1):

Try and use `fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter)` instead of `fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter)` after `fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter)`, because you need to add your `filter` to `fileChooser` and then setting it as default value.

Here is the link with good example:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomizingaJFileChooser.htm

Comment: I believe that modern Java adds the filter when you set if it is not already in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code!

```
private void btnChangeFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ArffFilter());
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this); 
        ... 
}
```

Then

```
class ArffFilter extends FileFilter {

@Override
public boolean accept(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        return true;
    }
    String fileName = file.getName();
    int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 && i < fileName.length() - 1) {
        if (fileName.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase().equals("arff")) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return ".arff (Weka format)";
    }
}
```